# how can I install Drupal 7 with PHP 5.2 on a Windows Server 2003 machine with IIS 6.0 and SQL server 2000 running on it?

Tags: users, iis, database

What I have:

> 1. Drupal 7.0
> 2. PHP 5.2
> 3. IIS 6.0
> 4. SQL server Enterprise Manager 2003
> 5. SQL server 2000 running on local system(my database is on the same system.)
> 6. Windows Server 2003.(makes any difference?)

I am using VPN to connect to the production system.(relevant?)

> 7. I have added the Microsoft SQL Drivers 2.0 to the php/ext folder.
> 8. I have added the sqlsrv module to the database\includes as well.

Got the option to install Drupal to sql server which was the only option by default in this case (got a message that my server does not support multiple databases hence sql server was selected by default).

I have the following fields available to me in the database setup:

> The values I have entered are in []:
>
> 1. database type:radio button (selected by default--microsoft SQL server)
> 2. database name: [database_name]
> 3. database user name: [user_name]
> 4. database password: [password]
>
> Advanced options:
>
> 1. hostname: [localhost]
> 2. port: blank
> 3. prefix: blank

I get an `SQLState[20008]:SQL server native client [10.0] error: can't login.`

what are the possible reason for not being able to connect?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using SQL2000 in 2014 because it is not supported anymore. 
I have successfully connected to SQL 2008 version using SQLSRV module in Drupal.

I would do the following in this case:

- Make sure TCP\IP protocol is enabled and it is listening on some port which is not getting blocked by firewall.
- I would try connecting to the database server using IP address and port using enterprise manager first.
- I would look in my SQL error logs because it records the authentication failures there.

Please share what you observe.

Thanks
C

Comment: i know it is dumb to use SQL 2000 today. But it was for a client. Finally convinced them to use MySQL instead. will post when i get to deal with it again.